# How to get a python function to return object instead of string

Tags: python, xml, function, urllib2

I have a function:

```
def getXMLpayload(server):
    try:
        result = urllib2.urlopen('http://%s' % server, None, 15)
    except urllib2.URLError:
        return 'unknown'
    except:
        raise Exception('Unexpected response from server')
    return result
```

I want it to return a *urllib2* object so that in another function I can call the above function and then use its output like so:

```
xmlPayload = result.read()
    tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xmlPayload))
    root = tree.getroot()
```

I think it is currently returning a string instead, how would I get it to return a file-like object, namely what is returned by *urllib2.urlopen*?

Comment: Erm, `.fromstring()` as the name implies expects you to pass it a string, not an object. Are you sure you want to return an object? Furthermore, `ET.fromstring()` returns a tree; you don't have to then pass it to `ET.ElementTree` again.

Comment: Do you by chance mean a "file-like object" (as returned by urllib2.urlopen) instead of a "urllib2" object (which would be of type "module")?

Comment: @Amber Right, that is why I get the results of the object and store it in the string `xmlPayload` right before. Re your 2nd point, that would mean I no longer need, `root = tree.getroot()`, correct?

Comment: @Hyperboreus Yes, good catch. I'll update the question to better state my intent.

Comment: Your error handling is a little odd here. Why are you returning a special "unknown" string when there is a `URLError` and not just letting the exception bubble up?

Comment: @jme that has to do with the specifics of the REST service this script is talking to, that type behavior we want to know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not returning a string, but a file-like object.

If it were a string indeed, `result.read()` would raise an Error, because strings don't have a method `read`.

Once read, `xmlPayload` is a string which you can then pass to `ET.fromstring`.

Comment: Thanks. I was getting the following error, which I interpreted as meaning the function was not returning the object. Previously I had everything in one function, so it seemed likely that this was the cause when I changed it to two functions instead: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./facts.py", line 50, in <module>
    version = getVersion('localhost')
  File "./facts.py", line 40, in getVersion
    for elem in tree.iter(tag='version'):
AttributeError: ElementTree instance has no attribute 'iter'`

Comment: The error message says it all: `ElementTree` has no member `iter`. I think you want the member `iter` of `Element` not `ElementTree`.

Comment: Looks like it was an issue with the version of python i was running under. Iterparse is only supported on 2.7, and I am running 2.6.6